# why is the large gif image causing the app to flicker?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, gpu, hardware

There is electron js application + react. Necessary show many gif images, but on some devices observed flickering screen.
This was fixed on windows by adding the line `app.commandLine.appendSwitch('force_high_performance_gpu');`. The problem is seen on iMac. Graphic/Display:

```
Radeon Pro 575:

  Chipset Model: Radeon Pro 575
  Type: GPU
  Bus: PCIe
  PCIe Lane Width: x16
  VRAM (Total): 4 GB
  Vendor: AMD (0x1002)
  Device ID: 0x67df
  Revision ID: 0x00c4
  ROM Revision: 113-D000AA-931
  VBIOS Version: 113-D0001A1P-025
  EFI Driver Version: 01.00.931
  Metal: Supported, feature set macOS GPUFamily2 v1
  Displays:
    iMac:
      Display Type: Built-In Retina LCD
      Resolution: 5120 x 2880 Retina
      Framebuffer Depth: 30-Bit Color (ARGB2101010)
      Main Display: Yes
      Mirror: Off
      Online: Yes
      Rotation: Supported
      Automatically Adjust Brightness: No
```

Comment: This probably needs more information for anyone to be able to answer. Are they animated gifs? Do you suspect the number of gifs is the problem, or do you think that one of the gifs is to blame? Does it happen if you build an HTML page of those gifs and display them in a browser on the same machines? All browsers, or just chrome? (And then a whole host of questions about what html, how react is involved, etc.)

Comment: Yes, gif animated. Еhe problem is on a large gif. Doesn't play in browser